# Should there be a conjunction in "There are two bowls, each one obviously designed for a dog."?

Tags: sentence-construction, syntax

Is this sentence grammatical?

> There are two bowls, each one obviously designed for a dog.

Since I don't see a conjunction between two clauses, it looks like a run-on sentence to me. Maybe you can teach me something I should know?

Comment: Yes, it is grammatically correct and idiomatic. The part after the comma is a participial clause.https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/participle-clauses

Comment: @JavaLatte Thanks for the information. If there is without "each one" in this sentence, it makes sence for me to identify "obiviously designed for a dog" as a participial clause. How do you explain "each one"?

Comment: @DenAllan It's the same type of construction as this: *There are two bowls, one of which is red.* The use of *each one* in the original simply modifies what follows.

Comment: Hi @JasonBassford Which part of the sentence did you refer to when you said "what follows"?

Comment: @DenAllan What follows *each one* is *obviously designed for a dog*.

Comment: @JasonBassford But ‘modify’ means to restrict or add to the sense of...Don't you think it's 'obviously designed for a dog' modifying 'each one'?

Comment: @DenAllan No, I don't. Refer back to my first comment. I'll state it differently: *There are two bowls, **one** obviously deigned for a dog.* ***One*** modifies *designed for a dog*. In the same fashion *each one* does the same thing. If you like, change *each one* into *each in turn* or even *both of them*.

Comment: @JasonBassford I kind of accept it now. But if this is a simple sentence (one clause sentence) "Each bowl is obviously designed for a dog.", "is obviously designed for a dog" modifies "each bowl", right? And then if the sentence is "There are two bowls, each bowl obviously designed for a dog.", for it is a two clause sentence, "each bowl" modifies "obviously designed for a dog", and they together modify "two bowls"? Tell me if I am making the right sense of I am thinking, thanks.

Comment: @DenAllan Everything after the comma modifies (as a whole) what comes before the comma. Looking within the phrase after the comma is just reductive analysis. In fact, what comes after the comma could be considered an [appositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) phrase.

Comment: @JasonBassford How do you define appositive phrase? Popular online definitions refer to it representing as noun. But from your interpretation of the sentence, the phrase 'each one obviously designed for a dog' is not treated as noun.

Comment: @DenAllan *Each one* is a noun phrase, part of a longer noun phrase. And what it's in apposition to (*two bowls*) is also a noun phrase. *I ate an apple [noun], the fruit [noun] was red.* I earlier provided a link to the Wikipedia article that explains this.

Comment: @JasonBassford You think 'each one obviously designed for a dog' is a longer noun phrase while 'each one' modifies 'obviously designed for a dog'?

Answer (score -1):

Under a traditional analysis, there is only one clause here:

> There **are** two bowls, each one obviously designed for a dog.

In contrast, these two sentences involve one clause each, for a total of two:

> There **are** two bowls.   Each one **is** obviously designed for a dog.

One obvious difference is that the version with two clauses has two finite verbs.   Each finite verb creates a predicate, and each predicate is joined to a subject, and each subject/verb pairing constitutes a clause.   Another obvious difference is that each independent clause can act as a complete sentence.   Separating those clauses with nothing more than a comma would traditionally be described as a *comma splice error*.

The first example, the one that has only one clause, also includes a supplemental phrase.   This is an absolute phrase, consisting of the nominative phrase "each one" modified by a participial phrase "obviously designed for a dog".

It's not a reasonable interpretation to say that each bowl designed anything.   This "designed" isn't the past-tense form.   The "each one" isn't a subject and an actor.   Instead, it's a modificand and a patient.   We have the implication that someone or something designed each one.   Without the addition of a finite verb, "each one obviously designed for a dog" cannot stand as a complete sentence.

Given that the absolute construction is not a clause and that it cannot stand as a sentence on its own, separating it from that clause which it modifies as a supplement does not count as a *comma splice error*.   In fact, that doesn't count as an error of any kind.   It counts as grammatical standard English.